# best way to convert 8 bytes from an array to a 64bit integer C++

Tags: c++

I want to convert 8 elements from an array of `uint8_t` to a `uint64_t`.
Performance is very important here, which is why I'm asking.
I managed to do it with reinterpret_cast, it's by far the fastest way but I'm afraid to use it since I don't really know a lot about endianness dependency and in general most people say it's unsafe to use.

the other way is with a union, but it's 4 times slower.

```
    // running the function a million times
    uint64_t foo(uint8_t arr[8])
    {
        // first way: 0.5 - 1 ms
        return *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&arr[0]);
    
        union
        {
            uint64_t result;
            uint8_t  bytesArray[sizeof(uint8_t)];
        } u;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            // time = 4ms average
            memcpy(&u.bytesArray[i], &arr[0], sizeof(uint8_t));
            // time = 3.5ms average
            u.bytesArray[i] = arr[0];
        }
        return u.result;
    }
```

what should I do?

Comment: how did you measure?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and have you enabled optimizations?

Comment: Why not the simplest memcpy with sizeof(uint64_t)? All solutions above are UB. And the second is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried `uint64_t res; memcpy(&res, arr, sizeof(uint64_t)); return res;`?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I made a Timer class with chrono, I think I took it off one of The Cherno's videos on youtube.

Comment: the thing is, without the benchmarking code and more information on your compiler and what options you used the results are almost meaningless. Most importantly, did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't realise you can do that. it works as fast as the first option.
thank you, really helped

Comment: @NULL _"... since I don't really know a lot about endianness dependency ..."_, well, does that need to deal with data generated on different machine architectures, is that data sent over a network? If not, you don't need to worry about endianess, otherwise use [`htonll()` / `ntohll()`](https://illumos.org/man/3C/ntohll) to do that.

Comment: Just build the number in the usual manner. [The compiler will optimize accordingly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hzcd68), dealing with both processor-specific endianness and alignment issues. Here's what [Rob Pike has to say on the subject](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).